# How to pass 2 parameters in a route, but make one hidden in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, optional-parameters

I want to make an edit_Item functionality, but I'm having a little bit of trouble with routing when submiting the edited form. I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:
Route [userItems] not defined.
```

First of all, in my Edit page, I have a form which passes 2 arguments from the Items table (item_id and user_id) to the controller and it looks like this:

```
{!! Form::model($items, ['action' => ['ItemController@update', $items->id, $items->user_id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
    //Form inputs                    
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My Update controller looks like this:

```
public function update($id, $user_id){
    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
        'title'       => 'required',
        'description'      => 'required|description',
    );
    // store
    $items = Item::find($id);
    $items->title = Input::get('title');
    $items->description = Input::get('description');
    $items->save();

    // redirect
    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated item!');
    return Redirect::route('userItems');
}
```

And my Route with the Update method looks like this:

```
Route::put('/userItems/{id}/{user_id}', 'ItemController@update');
```

Now, when I submit I'm currently getting routed to:

```
http://localhost:8000/userItems/26/3
```

And I need to get routed to:

```
http://localhost:8000/userItems/3
```

**Any ideas on how to make the item_id(26) disappear from the route?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [hidden input](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_input_type.asp)

> Define a hidden field (not visible to a user).

Your form

```
{!! Form::model($items, ['action' => ['ItemController@update', $items->user_id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{$items->id}}">    
    //Form inputs                    
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Your route

```
Route::put('/userItems/{user_id}', 'ItemController@update');
```

Your controller

```
public function update($user_id){
    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
        'title'       => 'required',
        'description'      => 'required|description',
    );
    // store
    $item_id = Request::input('item_id');
    $items = Item::find($item_id);
    $items->title = Input::get('title');
    $items->description = Input::get('description');
    $items->save();

    // redirect
    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated item!');
    return Redirect::route('userItems');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the solution to my problem. but when I edited my code with your provided examples, I'm now getting the error: **InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:
    Route [items/userItems] not defined.**
I'm storing my userItems view in the items folder, that's why the route is items/userItems.

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more specific. You get this error when you post the form or when you try to access a specific url?

Comment: I get this when i submit/post the form. It routes me to the correct url now: **http://localhost:8000/userItems/5** but I this error: **InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [items/userItems] not defined** Even though, the url should work.